# Symfony 2 date input with only year selector

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

Is it possible to make a date input field, with only year selector widget in Symfony 2 FormBuilder, or should I use a simple text type input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [form customization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig):

```
{% block date_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
        {{ block('field_widget') }}
    {% else %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {{ date_pattern|replace({
                '{{ year }}':  form_widget(form.year),
                '{{ month }}': '',
                '{{ day }}': '',
            })|raw }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock date_widget %}
```

Comment: This is a bit of a hack that solves the problem but doesn't answer the question-- how do you do this with the FormBuilder?

Answer (score 16):

You can also use:

```
'choices' => range(Date('Y') - 4, date('Y'))
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use the choice field type, rather than hacking the date field type or just using text field type.

Using few basic php date/time functions, you will get what you need.

In FormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('yearfield', 'choice',
                    array(
                        'required' => true, 'choices' => $this->buildYearChoices()
                    ));
}

public function buildYearChoices() {
    $distance = 5;
    $yearsBefore = date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y") - $distance));
    $yearsAfter = date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y") + $distance));
    return array_combine(range($yearsBefore, $yearsAfter), range($yearsBefore, $yearsAfter));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach was giving me errors with validation:

```
{{ date_pattern|replace({
    '{{ year }}':  form_widget(form.year),
    '{{ month }}': '',
    '{{ day }}': '',
})|raw }}
```

I finallay solved the problem by adding css attributes to hide the fields:

```
{{ date_pattern|replace({
    '{{ year }}': form_widget(form.year),
    '{{ month }}': form_widget(form.month, { 'attr' : { 'style': 'display:none' }}), 
    '{{ day }}':  form_widget(form.day, { 'attr' : { 'style': 'display:none' }}),
})|raw }}
```

Comment: I want to do exactly the same thing. Could you please explain me how you do please?, I have this **error**: `Twig_Error_Runtime: Variable "date_widget" does not exist`

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks. (Why does it fix it?)
ps. Best answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125517/how-to-display-a-month-year-dropdown-in-symfony2/22612012#22612012)

Answer (score 1):

You can override 'date_pattern':

```
{{ form_row(form.fieldName, {'date_pattern': '<span style="display: none;">{{ day }}{{ month }}</span>{{ year }}'}) }}
```

**NOTE!** Hide fields with `display: none`, Do not remove them to pass validation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer here: [How to display a month-year dropdown in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125517/how-to-display-a-month-year-dropdown-in-symfony2/22612012#22612012)

Just use a different date_widget block (twig).

Answer (score -1):

A simpler method to get, for example, a five year range of years, with a choice type :

```
    'choices' => array(
        Date('Y') => Date('Y'),
        Date('Y') - 1 => Date('Y') - 1,
        Date('Y') - 2 => Date('Y') - 2,
        Date('Y') - 3 => Date('Y') - 3,
        Date('Y') - 4 => Date('Y') - 4,
    )
```

Note that is creates returns a string of the year selected.

Answer (score -2):

I have written my code this way and inserting in database is correct

```
->add('yearfield', 'datetime', array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'yyyy'
))
```