# Symony2 Form Templating Error - Variable "widget" does not exist

Tags: symfony, twig, formbuilder

I am trying to alter the date_widget using symfony2 and twig. I would like to display just the year.

After reading [Symfony 2 date input with only year selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035077/symfony-2-date-input-with-only-year-selector) and the symfony2 book chapter on templating forms I have copied the date_widget block into my template and am receiving the error:

Variable "widget" does not exist in bundle....

here is the code from my template:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}

{% block date_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
         {{ block('field_widget') }}
    {% else %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {{ date_pattern|replace({
                '{{ year }}': form_widget(form.year),
            })|raw }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock date_widget %}

....print form (generated though app/console generate:crud)

{% endblock %}
```

Any Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the date_widget block outside of the body block, and add the following code after the initial extends

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
```

now, your code should look like this

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block body %}

....print form (generated though app/console generate:crud)

{% endblock %}

{% block date_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
         {{ block('field_widget') }}
    {% else %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {{ date_pattern|replace({
                '{{ year }}': form_widget(form.year),
            })|raw }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock date_widget %}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming

Comment: Aha, that seemed to work! However my output then looks like this: (year select box)-{{ month }}-{{ day }} I updated my code to this:   '{{ year }}' : form_widget(form.year), '{{ month }}' : '', '{{ day }}' : '', '-' : '', This seems to remove the fields, however I now get a validation error on submit