# How to display a month-year dropdown in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

In my application, the user hsa to give a date by only selecting a month and a year in two dropdown lists. How can I achieve that?

Here is what I've tried so far :

In my Form :

```
$builder->add('date1', 'date', array(
 'widget'      => 'choice',
 'empty_value' => '',
 'format'      => 'MMMM-yyyy',
 'input'       => 'datetime',
 'years'       => range(date('Y'), date('Y') - 30, -1)
)
```

which actually works and displays it exactly as I want but when validating the form, I get an error :

```
This value is not valid
```

A screenshot of the wanted result :

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Currently, there is no easy solution to your issue. Btw, I had the same issue few days ago but mine is about minutes.. I have submit a [PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3846) (not yet merged), if you want, you can add your feature to it :)

Comment: Hi,  three years later, is there a easy solution, something like `$builder->add('mydate', 'date', array( 'format'=> 'ONLY YEAR')`?

Answer (score 12):

Example for credit card expiration date:

```
$builder->add('expirationDate', 'date', array(
 'label' => 'Expiration date',
 'widget' => 'choice',
 'empty_value' => array('year' => 'Year', 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day'),
 'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
 'input' => 'string',
 'data' => date('Y-m-d'),
 'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y') + 10),
));
```

Then you must render this field manually.

Your form's twig template:

```
{{ form_row(form.expirationDate, {'date_pattern': '<span style="display: none;">{{ day }}</span> {{ month }} <span class="delim">&#47;</span> {{ year }}'}) }}
```

Overriding `date_pattern` will hide day select. You will get **month / year** format.

Answer (score 9):

Very simple, datetime requires day!

You need to output day, something like this:

```
        ->add(
            'ccExpirationDate',
            'date',
            array(
                'format'          => 'MMM-yyyy',
                'years'           => range(date('Y'), date('Y')+12),
                'days'            => array(1),
                'empty_value'     => array('year' => '----', 'month' => '----', 'day' => false)
            )
        )
```

TWIG:

```
{{ 
    form_widget(
        form.payment.ccExpirationDate.day, 
        { 
            'attr': { 'style': 'display:none' } }
        ) 
}}
```

Comment: That is indeed what I did but in Javascript.

Comment: But still sf2 needs to know about the `day`, so you can make only one option, and use no empty_value for it, as in my example above

Comment: This no longer works as of Symfony 2.1 as the format is checked for the presence of Y, M, and D symbols. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8345

Answer (score 6):

@Oleg was pretty close to the correct answer. You have to use a view transformer to make sure that the DateTime gets a day.

```
/* In your formType.php */

$builder->add(
   $builder->create('date1', 'date', array(
       'format'      => 'MMMM-yyyyd', // you need to have 'y', 'M' and 'd' here
       'years'       => range(date('Y'), date('Y') - 30, -1)
   ))
   ->addViewTransformer(new IncompleteDateTransformer()));
)
```

Create a transformer:

```
class IncompleteDateTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
/**
 * Do nothing when transforming from norm -> view
 */
public function transform($object)
{
    return $object;
}

/**
 * If some components of the date is missing we'll add those. 
 * This reverse transform will work when month and/or day is missing
 *
 */
public function reverseTransform($date)
{
    if (!is_array($date)) {
        return $date;
    }

    if (empty($date['year'])) {
        return $date;
    }

    if (empty($date['day'])) {
        $date['day']=1;
    }

    if (empty($date['month'])) {
        $date['month']=1;
    }

    return $date;
}
}
```

Create a twig template where you use a custom form theme from the file itself:

```
{# example.html.twig #}
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block date_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
        {{ block('field_widget') }}
    {% else %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            <div class="datetime_widget">
                {{ date_pattern|replace({
                '{{ year }}': form_widget(form.year),
                '{{ month }}': form_widget(form.month),
                '{{ day }}':  '',
                })|raw }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock date_widget %}

<h2>Select a date</h2>
{{ form(form) }}
```

References:

- [Data transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)
- [Form customization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)
- [Choice type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html)

Comment: +1 I had to define the date_widget block in another template, otherwise it claimed the "widget" variable did not exist.

Comment: Golden, still works for SF5. I had to create a new form-type and pop the `addViewTransformer()` in there, otherwise the whole form was being transformed, which somehow didn't work. With a `YearOnlyChoiceType.php` that is referenced in the main form everything works as you outlined!

Answer (score 5):

I working on a custom form type which would allow to solve such problem. The solution is based on what @oleg-andreyev proposed. The logic wrapped to a form type.

Usage:

```
<?php
$builder->add('exp_date', 'payum_credit_card_expiration_date');
```

The form type code:

```
<?php
namespace Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CreditCardExpirationDateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        if ('choice' == $options['widget']) {
            if (empty($view['day']->vars['value'])) {
                $view['day']->vars['value'] = $view['day']->vars['choices'][0]->value;
            }

            $style = 'display:none';
            if (false == empty($view['day']->vars['attr']['style'])) {
                $style = $view['day']->vars['attr']['style'].'; '.$style;
            }

            $view['day']->vars['attr']['style'] = $style;
        }
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->replaceDefaults(array(
            'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y') + 9)
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'date';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'payum_credit_card_expiration_date';
    }
}
```

You can copy\paste it or register payum bundle and use this type from (will be available there in next major release).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using dropdown, but [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker) in `single_text`. For me to save month and year in separate fields in database would be difficult, because I'm ordering by this date. So I decided always to save the first day of the chosen month. I'm using [DatetimepickerBundle](https://github.com/stephanecollot/DatetimepickerBundle), and my custom form type looks like that:

```
class MonthPickerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'pickerOptions' => array(
                'autoclose' => true,
                'format' => 'mm/yyyy',
                'startView' => 'year',
                'minView' => 'year',
            )
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'collot_datetime';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'month_picker';
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image]