# Symfony - Just showing year instead of yy-mm-dd from timestamp field in view

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a form like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('name','text',array('label'=>'name'))
    ->add('startAt', 'datetime',array('label'=>'start:'))
    ->add('endAt', 'datetime',array('label'=>'end:'))
;
```

I try to show form in view with below lines:

```
<div class="start-at">
    {% block startAt %}
        {{ form_errors(form.startAt) }}
        {{ form_label(form.startAt) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.startAt) }}
    {% endblock startAt %}
</div>
```

And when I render page I see in browser something like this:

[image]

How I can show just year or month in view? I don't need another fields.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a month-year dropdown in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125517/how-to-display-a-month-year-dropdown-in-symfony2)

Comment: @bartek this is not duplicate dude. I wouldn't like to hide elements by css. I want to just show year.

Answer (score 0):

The type of your field is "**datetime**", try to use the "**date**" type if you just need the date.

See the official documentation here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html