# Symfont Twig set month year to selected value on form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I followed this post, to set up a month year widget for credit card expiry date:

[How to display a month-year dropdown in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125517/how-to-display-a-month-year-dropdown-in-symfony2)

Now I am trying to set the fields to the values selected during form submission. How do I do this?

My form Type:

```
$builder->add('card_expiration_date', 'date', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'widget' => 'choice',
            'empty_value' => array('year' => 'Year', 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day'),
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'input' => 'string',
            'data' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y') + 10)
        ));
```

Some of the things I've been trying to do are:

**Trial 1**:

```
{{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date.month, {'value': ccMonth}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date.year, {'value': ccYear}) }}
```

This sets the values correctly but the issue with this is that it still renders out the form.card_expiration_date

**Trial 2:**

```
{%  if ccMonth == '' and ccYear == ''  %}
    {{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date, {'date_pattern': '<span style="display: none;">{{ day }}</span> {{ month }} <span class="delim">&#47;</span> {{ year }}'}) }}
{% else %}
    {{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date, {'date_pattern': '<span style="display: none;">{{ day }}</span> {{ month }} <span class="delim">&#47;</span> {{ year }}', 'value':  cmonth~'/'~cyear  }) }}
{% endif %}
```

I am pretty sure there's a better way to set the value on my Trial 2. That just doesn't look right. Any help will be appreciated.

***EDIT***

**Trial 3:**

```
{%  if cmonth == '' and cyear == ''  %}
    {{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date, {'date_pattern': '<span style="display: none;">{{ day }}</span> {{ month }} <span class="delim">&#47;</span> {{ year }}'}) }}
{% else %}
    {{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date, {'date_pattern': '<span style="display: none;">{{ day }}</span> {{ month }} <span class="delim">&#47;</span> {{ year }}'}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date.month, {'value': cmonth}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date.year, {'value': cyear}) }}
{% endif %}
```

***EDIT2***

```
{% set ccMonth = cardInfo.card.expdate|slice(2, 2) %}
{% set cmonth = (cardInfo.card)? ((ccMonth starts with '0')? ccMonth|slice(1, 1) : ccMonth) : '' %}
{% set cyear = (cardInfo.card)? '20'~cardInfo.card.expdate|slice(0, 2) : '' %}

<div class="col-lg-8">
    {%  if cmonth == '' and cyear == ''  %}
        {{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date, {'date_pattern': '<span style="display: none;">{{ day }}</span> {{ month }} <span class="delim">&#47;</span> {{ year }}'}) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date, {'date_pattern': '<span style="display: none;">{{ day }}</span> {{ month }} <span class="delim">&#47;</span> {{ year }}'}) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date.month, {'value': cmonth}) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.card_expiration_date.year, {'value': cyear}) }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_errors(form.card_expiration_date) }}
</div>
```

***EDIT3***

Here's what I did. Not sure if it's the right way, but seems to work.

Controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new BillingType($em, $ccInfo), $billing, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('save_billing', array('id' => $id)),
        'method' => 'POST'
    ));
```

BillingType:

```
function __construct(EntityManager $em, $ccInfo)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->ccInfo = $ccInfo;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    if( ! is_null($this->ccInfo['card']))
    {
        if (substr($this->ccInfo['card']['expdate'], -2, 1) == '0')
        {
            $ccMonth = substr($this->ccInfo['card']['expdate'], -1, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            $ccMonth = substr($this->ccInfo['card']['expdate'], -2, 2);
        }
        $ccYear = '20'.substr($this->ccInfo['card']['expdate'], 0, 2);

        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ccYear.'-'.$ccMonth.'-01'));
    }

$builder->add('card_expiration_date', 'date', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'widget' => 'choice',
            'empty_value' => array('year' => 'Year', 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day'),
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'input' => 'string',
            'data' => $date,
            'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y') + 10)
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither. You should set the data of the underlying object (or array). The `form_widget` view helper will already render the value if one is present. If you're in a controller context, there's already a method for doing this

```
$form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());
```

This will bind the request data to the form's data object.  I can help you iron out your specific implementation if you want to share more details.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by controller context. As you see in the Form type, the field is not mapped. See EDIT 2 in my post. Can't seem to post all the code here.

Comment: A field not being mapped means that it's not going to be persisted to database. But that doesnt mean it can't be access via Request. What @Peter Bailey means is that binding the current request to your form (after submit) your form fields should be automatically populated with the data they were holding before submission.

Comment: I am trying to set the values using twig. How would I do it from the controller context then? An example maybe?

Is there a way I can set the card_expiration_date.day, card_expiration_date.month and card_expiration_date.year explictly on twig's side?

Comment: You probably can by doing `{% set form.field.vars.value = 'value' %}` before any call to `form_widget` but you really shouldn't do that. Setting object values is not a templating concern and you're asking for maintenance headaches by violating that separation.