# Disable days and month from Symfony DateType::class

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

```
->add('attendFrom', DateType::class, array(
                'widget' => 'choice',
                'html5' => false,
                'months' => array(),
                'days' => array(),
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Start year, e.g., 1980 ',
                )
            ))
```

There is type from which I try to disable days and month. I want to show only years. Is this is possible?

I had find some solution to hide days and months from a twig but I wonder if I can disable this from FormType.

Cheers

Comment: What makes this field specific then? It is, basically, a simple `text` with integer check or a `choice` with multiple years given, right?

Comment: HI Jovan, I think this is common Symfony problem with DateType. With DataType::class this is choice with multiple years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `yyyy` in `format` option

**Form:**

```
->add('attendFrom', DateType::class, array(
    'format' => 'yyyy',
    'widget' => 'choice',
    'html5' => false,
    'attr' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Start year, e.g., 1980 ',
    )
))
```

> **Update-1**

Hide month and day control in twig

**TWIG**:

```
{{ 
    form_widget(
        form.formName.attendFrom.day, 
        { 
            'attr': { 'style': 'display:none' }
        }
    )
    form_widget(
        form.formName.attendFrom.month, 
        { 
            'attr': { 'style': 'display:none' }
        }
    ) 
}}
```

Ref: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10125517/2689199)

Comment: It's now mandatory (since Symfony 3.0) to include "y", "M" and "d" letters into "format" option. So given answer is not going to work on newer code base.

Answer (score 3):

You can just simply create a ChoiceType field with

```
...
'choices' => range(date('Y') - 10, date('Y') + 10),
...
```

However, if you need to have a DateTime object after submitting your form, then you should define your own [View Transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html).

In your form type class add the following lines:

```
public function buildForm(
    FormBuilderInterface $builder,
    array $options
)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            $builder->create('attendFrom', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'choice',
            ])
            ->addViewTransformer(new IncompleteDateTransformer())
        );
}
```

Also, create your own View Transformer:

```
/**
 * Class IncompleteDateTransformer.
 */
class IncompleteDateTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function transform($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            return $value;
        }

        if (empty($value['year'])) {
            return $value;
        }

        $value['day'] = $value['day'] ?? 1;
        $value['month'] = $value['month'] ?? 1;

        return $value;
    }
}
```

And after that, render only `attendFrom.year` field or hide `attendFrom.month` and `attendFrom.day` fields via `attr` argument in form_row/form_widget function. See Gopal Joshi answer for example on hiding other fields.