# DateType Field only month and year Symfony 5

Tags: symfony

I want my DateType field in my form to show only the month and year. 
I tried a lot things but it's not working.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()

            ->add('date',  DateType::class, [
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->getForm();
```

Do yo know how i can achieve this ?

Edit: Here is my twig template

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
                <div class="form-row align-items-end">
                    <div class="col">
                        {{ form_row(form.company) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        {{ form_row(form.date) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">{% trans %}Search{% endtrans %}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the view code (html.twig page code).

Comment: Yes sorry, it's done

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54288242/9876136) helps?

Comment: what exactly have you tried so far, have you tried both `format` and `input_format` options for the field? https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You will not be able to remove the day in PHP or Twig because the DateTime object needs it

I suggest you hide it in css. Example, I had to hide the year a form :

```
#statistic_search_start_day {
    display: none;
}
```

Then you can customize the missing field in PHP (Form event or controller)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something that the symfony doc recommends to do:

```
$builder->add('date', DateType::class, [
    // renders it as a single text box
    'widget' => 'single_text',
]);
```

Then in your twig template you can style the input however you want. For example hide it and create 2 select fields which would override the input value with an change event

```
<select id="month">
... options
</select>

<select id="year">
...options
</select>

<script>
const monthSelect = document.querySelector('#month');
const yearSelect = document.querySelector('#year');
monthSelect.addEventListener('change', () => { here override month in your single text }
yearSelect.addEventListener('change', () => { here override year in your single text }
</script>
```

And here you go, fully customizable datetime picker